# Python ORM for MS-Access

Tags: python, ms-access, orm

I need to use a Python ORM with a MS-Access database (in Windows).
My first searches are not really succesfull :

- SQLAlchemy : no MS Access support in the two last versions.
- DAL from Web2Py : no Access (??)
- Storm : no MS Access
- sqlobject: no MS Access
- dejavu : seems OK for MS Access but
  is the project alive ?

Any ideas or informations are welcome ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web2py recently updated their DAL making it much easier to add support for new db engines.  I don't believe there is currently native Jet (MS Access) support, but the existing SQL Server support could probably be modified without much effort to provide MS Access support.  The latest version of the web2py DAL is a single stand-alone .py file, so it's not a "heavy" package.

For what it's worth, I've successfully used the web2py DAL as a stand-alone module with SQL Server after initially trying and giving up on SQLAlchemy.  In fairness to SQLAlchemy, I had used the web2py DAL as part of the framework and was already comfortable with it.

Comment: Yes Web2py seems to be a good concurent for my choice but as I am  very newbie in Python I would found a 'ready to go' solution.

Comment: @philnext I probably would choose DAL and ask on Web2py discussion group, in the past something similar (though for DB2) has already been asked and Massimo Di Pierro [was in favour](http://groups.google.com/group/web2py/tree/browse_frm/thread/473e320d1c728a82/c52609a95f48a901?rnum=1&_done=%2Fgroup%2Fweb2py%2Fbrowse_frm%2Fthread%2F473e320d1c728a82%2Fa03c9e0fe2b31ee3%3F#doc_e02a1489115756b4) of providing an implementation for the missing feature. Maybe you could try too, who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Since Sep 2019 there is a Microsoft Access dialect for SQLAlchemy, called [sqlalchemy-access](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-access/). It uses the package `pyodbc`.

Installation:

```
pip install pyodbc sqlalchemy sqlalchemy-access
```